# how memfd_create and fexecve works together

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, exec, race-condition

From the [man page of `fexecve`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fexecve) and [unerlying `execveat` syscall](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execveat.2.html), it is specified that:

> The file descriptor fd must be opened read-only, and the caller must have permission to execute the file that it refers to.

However, I tried with `memfd_create` a writable `fd` and `fexecve` it and it works just fine.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#include <unistd.h>

#include <err.h>
#include <errno.h>

size_t min(size_t x, size_t y)
{
    return x > y ? y : x;
}

/**
 * @param len != 0
 */
void fdput(int fd, const char *str, size_t len)
{
    size_t cnt = 0;
    do {
        ssize_t result = write(fd, str + cnt, min(len - cnt, 0x7ffff000));
        if (result == -1) {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            err(1, "%s failed", "write");
        }
        cnt += result;
    } while (cnt != len);
}
#define fdputc(fd, constant_str) fdput((fd), (constant_str), sizeof(constant_str) - 1)

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int fd = memfd_create("script", 0);
    if (fd == -1)
        err(1, "%s failed", "memfd_create");

    fdputc(fd, "#!/bin/bash\necho Hello, world!");

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        const char * const argv[] = {"script", NULL};
        const char * const envp[] = {NULL};
        fexecve(fd, (char * const *) argv, (char * const *) envp);

        err(1, "%s failed", "fexecve");
    } else if (pid == -1)
        err(1, "%s failed", "fork");

    wait(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

However, is this approach (hack) safe?

If the parent calls `lseek(memfd, 0, SEEK_SET)` and `write(memfd, ...)` when the child is `fexecve`ing the `fd`, what will happen?

How would the linux kernel handle this kind of situation?

Would linux kernel mark the content of `fd` copy-on-write at a certain point in `execveat` so that it's no longer modifiable?

Answer (score 0):

(It's been a while so probably doesn't matter anymore, but for reference...)

If the parent modifies the content of the file, it's screwing up whatever you're going to execute, which means arbitrary execution or crash. The kernel doesn't care, it just maps the memory of the file at some address the the vfs does its job of exposing it to processes; execve is basically just a mmap (shared).

Normally when you call execve on a file, the kernel will use `deny_write_access` which will basically make the file unmodifiable: trying to open with O_WRONLY a file currently being executed with fail with ETXTBSY, and conversely trying to execute a file that's being open in write mode will fail with the same error.

For memfd, though, that check doesn't seem to work as can be tested easily from your snippet -- make your shell script sleep a few seconds and print a second line, and the parent process call pwrite at the offset of the second line after a shorter sleep (making sure exec happened), and you'll get your modified line out.

Just don't do that. If it's your code, it's easy enough to just close the fd on the parent side, or even just create the memfd in the child between fork and exec.

If you want to protect yourself from that otherwise, memfd can allow sealing, so you can restrict truncate/write operations to make sure the content will not be modified.
Allowing exec without seal is actually probably a bug as there really isn't any reason to not mark the file as being written to (inode->i_writecount > 0) before sealing; but changing that now is probably going to be considered an ABI breakage so it's probably going to stay.

Note though, linux 6.3 introduced a sysctl to forbid exec, `vm.memfd_noexec`, as well as `MFD_NOEXEC_SEAL` and `MFD_EXEC` flags for the easy mode case.
Before that selinux or apparmor could also be used for forbid executing from a memfd; so it's not like it'll work everywhere -- it's usually frowned upon by administrators and should only be allowed for well known cases (usually JIT), with well defined boundaries.
You can bet it'll be disallowed more often than not in the future.

(EDIT: uh, the [commit that introduced that sysctl](https://git.kernel.org/torvalds/c/105ff5339f498af74e60d7662c8f1c4d21f1342d) says value 2 rejects any mapping without NOEXEC set, but it actually seems to allow for explicit EXEC as well.. I don't get it. Oh, well.)